# Usage of ein beliebig- and einzeln-

Tags: difference

What is the difference between ein beliebig- and einzeln-? Both mean 'any' but when are they used?

1. Du kannst ***einen beliebigen*** Knopf drücken.
2. Du kannst ***einen einzelnen*** Knopf drücken.

Comment: Who claims that "einzeln" means "any"? It doesn't. Its meaning is "single", "individual".

Comment: The first sentence means "an arbitrary button". The second sentence is not correct, "einzigen Knopf" is more appropriate. Both mean single but in a different context. "Einzig" in total and "einzeln" with multiple elements.  For example: "einen einzelnen Knopf pro Formular".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't really see how those words could be related. But strictly speaking the question makes sense, because the difference does exist – and is huge!

- *beliebigen Knopf drücken* means that you don't need to choose a criterion to press the button. A random choice is allowed.
- *einzeln*, on the other hand, stresses the fact that pressing *a single button* will work – just as pressing many will:

  > Du kannst einen einzelnen Knopf drücken (und das reicht, um den Bildschirm zu entsperren).